# I want to create a pin screen like retro phone

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to create a pin screen like retro phone where I have circular numbers and a ring above that so when I rotate the ring from where I start rotate I want to select that number.

Here you can see what I want to do:

[image]

But when I rotate from 2 it shows the wrong number as selected. Here is the code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            RotaryDialView()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct RotatableImageView: View {
    @State private var rotationAngle: Angle = .zero
    @GestureState private var dragOffset: CGSize = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ZStack{
                Image("iconr")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 400, height: 400)
                    .rotationEffect(rotationAngle, anchor: .center)
                VStack{}.frame(width: 600, height: 600)
                    .background(Color.red.opacity(0.1))
                    .gesture(DragGesture()
                        .onChanged({ value in
                            withAnimation{
                                let dragVector = CGVector(dx: value.location.x, dy: value.location.y)
                                let radius = atan2(dragVector.dy, dragVector.dx)
                                
                                
                                var angle = radius * 180 / .pi
                                if angle < 0 {angle = 360 + angle}
                                
                                rotationAngle += Angle(radians: Double(angle / 600))
                            }
                        })
                            .onEnded({ value in
                                withAnimation{
                                    rotationAngle = .zero
                                }
                            })
                    )
                
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RotaryDialView: View {
    let numbers: [Int] = Array(0...9)
    @State var selectedNumber: Int = 0
    @State var pinArray: [Int] = []

    @State private var dialRotationAngle: Double = 0
    @State private var lastNumber: Int?
    @State private var initialRotationAngle: Double = 10
    
    @State private var rotationAngle: Angle = .zero
    @GestureState private var dragOffset: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var initialDragAngle: Angle = .zero
    @State var cirleSize:CGFloat = 310

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("number: \(selectedNumber) ")
            ZStack {
                
                Circle()
                    .stroke(style:StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 85))
                    .frame(width: cirleSize, height: cirleSize)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    
                Image("iconr2")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 380, height: 380)
                    .rotationEffect(rotationAngle, anchor: .center)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                VStack{}.frame(width: 400, height: 400)
                    .background(Color.white.opacity(0.1))
                    
                
                ZStack{
                    ForEach(numbers, id: \.self) { number in
                        VStack{
                            Text("\(number)")
                                .font(.title)
                                .foregroundColor(selectedNumber == number ? .red : .white)
                                .rotationEffect(.degrees(dialRotationAngle))
                            
                            
                        }
                        .position(getPositionForNumber(number: number))
                        .padding(.all , 50)
                    }
                }.frame(width: 400, height: 400)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(16))
                    .gesture(DragGesture()
                        .onChanged({ value in
                            withAnimation{
                                if initialDragAngle == .zero {
                                    initialDragAngle = rotationAngle
                                }
                                
                                let dragVector = CGVector(dx: value.location.x, dy: value.location.y)
                                let radius = atan2(dragVector.dy, dragVector.dx)
                                
                                
                                var angle = radius * 180 / .pi
                                if angle < 0 {angle = 360 + angle}
                                
                                rotationAngle += Angle(radians: Double(angle / 600))
                            }
                        })
                            .onEnded({ value in
                                withAnimation{
//                                    selectedNumber = getNumberForAngle(angle: initialDragAngle.degrees)
                                    
                                    let angleDifference = rotationAngle - initialDragAngle
                                    let angleInDegrees = angleDifference.degrees
                                    let numberChange = Int(angleInDegrees / 36)
                                    let finalNumber = (selectedNumber + numberChange) % 10
                                    selectedNumber = finalNumber // Corrected here
                                    
                                    rotationAngle = .zero
                                    initialDragAngle = .zero
                                }
                            })
                    )
                
            }
            .frame(width: 400, height: 400)
        }
    }

    func getPositionForNumber(number: Int) -> CGPoint {
        let angle = 2 * .pi * Double(number) / Double(numbers.count) + dialRotationAngle
        let radius: CGFloat = 160
        let x = radius * CGFloat(cos(angle)) + 150
        let y = radius * CGFloat(sin(angle)) + 150
        return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    }
    
    func getNumberForAngle(angle: CGFloat) -> Int {
        let angleInDegrees = angle * 180 / .pi
        var number = Int(angleInDegrees / 36)
        if number < 0 { number += 10 }
        return number % 10
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a pin screen?

Comment: pin screen means password screen where i want 4 numbers as password like 1234 so i rotate number like first 1 than 2 and 3 and 4 so all thing work properly but numbers are incorrect which i got

Comment: How do you define a successful dial gesture? In the old dials you had to turn until the „blocker“, otherwise it was faulty.

Comment: currently im just getting drag if user drag it i use as selected number

Comment: `RotatableImageView` is unused. For reproducibility: Images "icon" and "iconr2" are missing, what are they?

Comment: that is just image which i use to rotate when user drag